# Is there a way to use a player name in an entity tag?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I want to name an armorstand based on the nearest player using the @p parameter
for example,
I want /summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:@p}
an if "@p" was Bob, then the armorstand would be named Bob.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What all have you tried?

Comment: There is no way to do this AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way of doing so. If there's only a small list of players to choose from, you could use a command block for each player, but otherwise it'll either take too much command blocks to do it for each name.